# After deleting all nodes, QuickLaunch throws "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

Tags: 2013, powershell, quick-launch

If QuickLaunch has nodes, the following causes the error "You cannot call a method on a null valued expression". If not, it carries on as normal.

```
$nodes = $subWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch
write-host $nodes.Count
while($nodes.Count -gt 0)
{
    $nodes[0].Delete()
}
write-host $nodes.Count  #error
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake. The error happens in the while loop.

Apparently $nodes.Count never changes, so the while loop runs until $nodes[0] is null and $nodes[0].Delete() throws the error. I changed the while condition to catch it.

```
$nodes = $subWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch
write-host $nodes.Count
while($nodes.Count -gt 0 -and $nodes[0] -ne $null) 
{
    $nodes[0].Delete()
}
write-host $nodes.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

I think after deleting the last node, QuickLaunch (SPNavigationNodeCollection) is not exists anymore as no child items exists in the database. That why  $nodes is null in your example.

Comment: do you know how I would add new nodes to it then, after deleting everything? currently I have to run my script twice - first time to clear existing nodes and the second time to add new nodes, because quicklaunch is null after deleting but not null if I run again

Comment: You can use web.Navigation.AddToQuickLaunch: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.addtoquicklaunch(v=office.14).aspx